# NSSet -member to check equality of NSValue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, equality, nsset

I have a `NSSet` containing many thousands of `NSValue` objects (wrapping `CGPoints`). I would like to very quickly find if a given `CGPoint` value exists in the `NSSet`. It seems to me that the `member:` method of an `NSSet` might do the job here, except that it checks for equality using `isEqual:`. `NSValue` objects use `isEqualToValue:`, and so when I execute the code:

```
[mySet member:valueToCheck];
```

it actually causes Xcode to crash.

1) Is there some way to use a custom equality check to make this work for `NSValue` objects?

2) Is this even the best approach (i.e. is `member:` quick enough in the first place)? The scenario is that I have a `NSSet` containing a large number of points representing pixels on the screen (iPad). Later on I need to bombard that set with many thousands of points per second to see if they exist in the set. My approach seems crude for achieving this. I thought about creating something like a huge 2-dimensional bit array, with each index representing a pixel on screen. Once I know the point I'm testing for, I can just jump straight to that point in the array and check for a 1 or 0... does this sound better or worse?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you get this to a simple reproducible case?  For example, I just tried:

```
NSValue *v = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)];
NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:v];
NSLog(@"%@", [s member:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)]]);
```

But it works just fine.

**edit**

`-isEqual:` is not the problem:

```
NSValue *v1 = [NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(1, 1)];
NSValue *v2 = [NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(1, 1)];
NSLog(@"%d", [v1 isEqual:v2]); //logs "1"
```

`-hash` is not the problem:

```
NSLog(@"%d", ([v1 hash] == [v2 hash])); //logs "1"
```

They are different objects:

```
NSLog(@"%d", (v1 != v2)); //logs "1"
```

The problem is in your code.  Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: Hmmm now you mention it - it does seem to be working for me now. I suppose it must have been a problem with Xcode itself (it was causing Xcode itself to have a fit, rather than the application). I just need to check if the speed is good enough now, back in a minute...!

Comment: Yes, I think I just ran into an Xcode 4 hissy-fit. It's not crashing anymore thankfully. I just tested the speed of this approach and it seems that it *may* be fast enough. Potentially the `NSSet` _could_ reach a capacity of over 750,000 objects, and would need to test approximately 10,000 points per second to be fast enough. It **just** seems to manage this - it may not quite be enough for me. I am surprised at the speed of it though... faster than I thought at first. I need to do more thorough tests before I know for sure if it's good enough though.

Comment: `- (void)testNSValuePointHash
{
  NSValue *v1 = [NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(1,1)];
  NSValue *v2 = [NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(2,2)];

  STAssertTrue([v1 hash] != [v2 hash], nil);
}`

This test fails, and that might be related. I think it is a bug in NSValue, isn't it? All NSValues with points where the two axes have the same value seem to give a hash of 0.

Answer (score 1):

To answer no. 2:

I don't know how NSSet is implemented internally, but considering that you know you are storing points (with X and Y), I think you would be better by implementing your own partitioning algorithm. Personally I would choose my own implementation over NSSet if you say you have thousands of points.

Storing huge 2-dimensional arrays for each pixel, would probably be the fastest way, but it will kill you in terms of memory consumption. You need something fast, but also lightweight.

There are a lot of algorithms out there and you can find them by searching "spatial partitioning algorithms" on wikipedia or google. It also depends on your programming skills, and how much time you are willing to invest in this.

For example, a pretty simple one would be to implement a quad-tree, where you start by diving your screen(or area) in 4 equal parts. Then if and where is needed, you divide that specific cell also in 4 parts. And you do this until each cell contains a small enough number of points so that you can brute-force test all of them.
You can find a very good description on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Hope this helps,

Comment: A very useful answer, thanks. If I were to use a boolean array (if this is possible, I haven't ever made one before!), then 100kB would be needed - I'm not sure that would blow up my app, but I suppose it may be unnecessary if a spatial partitioning algorithm could achieve the same results quick enough. Otherwise I'd tend towards the simplest solution.

Comment: Having integer coordinates, and only within the ipad screen it would take around 800KB (storing one byte per pixel) + overhead. It's not that big. However, I think I would still choose a smarter algorithm :). I have no idea what your application is about and it all comes down to your specific needs.

Comment: This is a good idea, **but only if you've proven that using `NSSet` is a bottleneck**.  `NSSet` is over 20 years old, and the Foundation developers have had all that time to tweak it to be insanely efficient. (ditto all the other collections) If you can prove that it's faster to *not* use `NSSet`, then by all means use something else. But go with the simple route first, and then profile and measure where your slowdowns are.

Comment: At the moment it's very hard to say if NSSet will be a bottleneck - it appears to be right on the border of the performance I'm in need of. This answer was very helpful, and I may end up using one of the approaches mentioned here, however my main question was regarding the use of `NSSet`, so I've marked the response from @Dave as the answer. Thanks

Comment: By comparison, the massive boolean array approach is about as fast as it can get, it seems. With an array: `BOOL boolArray[748][1004]` and 25,000 test points, it only takes 0.017 seconds. What's more, loading the array with values is instantaneous in comparison to loading the `NSSet`. I still need to see whether an array of 800kB is feasible in my app. Performance is *very* critical in this case, for the sake of a decent user experience, and this approach is certainly nippy.

Answer (score 1):

`[mySet member:valueToCheck]` should not be crashing. NSValue's `isEqual:` works fine when I try it here, and in fact probably calls `isEqualToValue:` when given another NSValue to compare to. Is `valueToCheck` really an NSValue, or is it a CGPoint?

There is no way to override the default hash and comparison methods *for NSSet*. But NSSet is toll-free bridged with [`CFSetRef`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSetRef/Reference/reference.html), and you *can* easily specify custom hashing and comparison methods there:

```
CFSetCallBacks callbacks = kCFTypeSetCallBacks;
callbacks.equal = customEqualFunction;
callbacks.hash = customHashFunction;
NSMutableSet *set = (NSMutableSet *)CFSetCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &callbacks);
```

The constraints on these functions are presumably the same as on NSObject's `hash` and `isEqual:` methods, anything that is equal must have the same hash. The C-style prototypes for `customEqualFunction` and `customHashFunction` are described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSetRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFSetEqualCallBack) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSetRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFSetHashCallBack).

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to subclass `NSSet` and override `member:` to do your own comparison. Your own comparison could then simple call `isEqualToValue:`. Have a look at the subclassing notes in the [`NSSet` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Another approach would be to add a category to `NSValue` that implements `isEqual:`. In this case I'd prefer subclassing because it's a more constrained solution.

Comment: No. Do not subclass `NSSet`. It's a class cluster, and subclassing it is a non-trivial task.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: Subclassing `NSSet` is fine. I agree it's not commonly necessary, but it's fine to do. The documentation does not state that it is a class cluster. Here's extract from the `NSSet` documentation:
"Subclassing Notes
There should be little need of subclassing. If you need to customize behavior, it is often better to consider composition instead of subclassing.

Methods to Override

In a subclass, you must override all of its primitive methods:

count
member:
objectEnumerator"

Comment: It *is* a class cluster. The documentation says that it's toll free bridged to `CFSet`, and toll free bridging only works because of class clusters.

Comment: @Dave Fair enough. Your answer is more consider. (I currently only have web access so was unable to test my proposed solution.) It's a bit odd that there's no mention of it being a class cluster in docs. The NSArray docs makes it very clear.

Comment: plus, I have the source here in front of me ;) You can verify this for yourself by instantiating an `NSSet` and finding out what the name of the instance's `class` is.  It's an `NSCFSet` (`NSCF*` is the indicator that the class is TFB'd).

Answer (score -1):

It's not just a problem with `-isEqual:`, you may also have an issue with the [-hash](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGFFCH) method. If you want to use an NSSet, you should probably create a custom class that wraps the CGPoint.  `-isEqual:` is then trivial and `-hash` could be implemented by some method of combining the bits of both coordinates and then treating them as a NSUInteger.

You'll also want to implement the `NSCopying` protocol which is also trivial if your points are immutable (just retain and return self in `-copyWithZone:`).

Comment: -1 `-hash` is not the problem. You can create two unique `NSValue` objects that contain the same `CGPoint`, and they will have the same `-hash` value and will return `YES` from `-isEqual:`

Comment: @DaveDeLong: that's a bit of a harsh down vote considering that the bulk of my answer is an alternative to using NSValue.