# Constructing a NSArray of UIView objects with unique center

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, nsarray

I have a array of custom UIView objects with 2 or more objects having same center and I have to construct another array from it with distinct centers. What is the best way to do it?

I tried with below piece of code but it does not work.

```
self.distinctObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:iAllObjects.count];

for (MyCustomView *customView in iAllObjects)
{
     BOOL hasDuplicate = [[self.distinctObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.center == %@", customView.center]] count] > 0;

     if (!hasDuplicate) {
                [self.distinctObjects addObject:customView];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `struct`'s (in your case `center` is a `CGPoint`) in `NSPredicate`. Also comparing floating-point values directly isn't a good idea.
You should follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6528910/1990236). Just replace `[annotation coordinate].latitude` with `myView.center.x`, `[annotation coordinate].longitude` with `myView.center.y`, and so on. It should be easy.

BTW your code has O(n^2) complexity, but maybe that's not a problem if the array is small.

Comment: I have fixed this. Please see my code (in answer below). I am looping once in the main array and checking for duplicates in a temp array. Do you think there can be a better way of doing it?

Comment: `NSSet` comes to my mind mind, when thinking about checking for duplicates. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5719584/1990236) you've got a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with below piece of code:

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueCenters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:iAllObjects.count];
self.distinctObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:iAllObjects.count];

for (MyCustomView *customView in iAllObjects)
{
    if (![uniqueCenters containsObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:customView.center]]) {
        [uniqueCenters addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:customView.center]];

        [self.beacons addObject:customView];
    }
}
```